# How to Import Bookmarks Well in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I would like to import bookmarks in Firefox, from Google Chrome. 
There is a tool for that in Google Chrome but not in Firefox. 
I cannot find any such a tool in Firefox, not even having a possibility to include bookmarks from a file. 
I am using Firefox 45.2 in OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 but the situation should be the same across all platforms. 
There are extensions such as Xmarks which provide a lot of features. I do not want that but just import bookmarks to Firefox.

### End result of Private's answer

I complete steps described in [Private's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1066142/2005).
You get a folder called *Bookmarks from Google Chrome*. 
I feel this kind of behaviour humiliating; making an extra folder for another browser's bookmarks. 
I would like to get those bookmarks as they are in my Google Chrome; some to Bookmark bar and some in the Bookmark Manager. 
Removing the bookmark folder in Firefox, you lose all your bookmarks in Firefox. 
So Firefox's Bookmark management seems to be incomplete. It seems

- Firefox only has one level management of bookmarks - bookmark bar
- OR Firefox is downgrading users coming from Google Chrome by Purpose or is afraid of mixing up existing bookmarks from elsewhere because they cannot control the flow of bookmarks.

---

How can you import Bookmarks Well in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an additional extension to achieve this. Mozilla Firefox has a built in feature for this job.
See [Import bookmarks and other data from Google Chrome](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-google-chrome).

**Steps:**

> 1. Click the Bookmarks button and select `Show All Bookmarks` to open the Library window. [image: Import Data from Another Browser]
> 2. From the toolbar in the Library window, click `Import and Backup` and choose `Import Data from Another Browser...`
> 3. In the Import Wizard window that appears, select **Chrome**, then click `Next`.
> 4. Firefox will list the types of settings and information it can import. Select the items you want to import, then click `Next`.
>
>    - **Cookies**: Small bits of information stored on your computer by some websites that are used to keep you logged in, store your options, or do other things.
>    - **Browsing History**: Information on the sites you have visited.
>    - **Bookmarks**: Web pages you have saved in your Chrome bookmarks.
> 5. Click `Finish`. The items you selected should now be imported.

Comment: Please add back the link to the quoted material, and read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). Make sure you "block quote" the quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)).